# Standard way to initialize and use a struct

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc

Let's say that I need to parse a line in C and fill up a struct such as:

```
line = "GET /hello HTTP/1.1\r\n";

typedef struct {
  char* method;
  char* path;
  char* protocol;
} http_request_line;

parse_http();
```

I would like to call a function that would return me a `http_request_line`. I am not sure about a few things:

Where should I initialize the struct allocate the memory? Should it be in my calling method (e.g. `main()`) and giving it a pointer so the function would fill it up? Or should it be in `parse_http()` and return a copy of it?

```
request_http_line parse_http(char* line);
request_http_line* parse_http(char* line);
void parse_http(char* line, request_http_line *rhl);
```

As the structure has fields with undefined length (for example, the method can have variable length ex GET, HEAD...), should I create a constructor and destructor method instead?

Comment: `*request_http_line parse_http(char* line);` makes little sense.  Suggest `request_http_line *parse_http(char* line);`

Comment: All your concepts are valid - the best depends on the larger use case.  Consider posting sample a sample complete use.

Comment: You can actually declare and allocate within a function that returns a pointer to a `http_request_line`. If allocation succeeds, you return the allocated pointer, if it fails, you return `NULL`. You validate the return back in the caller. That's a pretty straight-forward approach.

Comment: Wow that was super fast, thank you so much. It makes sense to allocate the struct within the function and return a NULL pointer in case of error. There are functions like `accept` or `getaddrinfo` that require pointers to struct and those structures get filled in. Is it because those system calls need to return an int and this is the only way to return a result otherwise? Then, I am guessing they are in charge of allocating the memory for us?

Comment: C doesn't have constructor and destructor methods, add c++ tag

Comment: @Vineet -- C doesn't have methods at all, but OP has posted C code. Don't suggest irrelevant tags based on a poor choice of words.

Comment: The reason for accepting a pointer to a struct and filling it in is that the caller might create the struct on the stack, or as a field of a larger struct.

Comment: Don't forget, that things might fail and you want to return an error state somehow as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a separate "constructor" for the type itself:

```
request_http_line* create_empty_request  (void)
{
  request_http_line* obj = malloc( sizeof *obj );
  obj->method = NULL;
  obj->path = NULL;
  obj->protocol = NULL;

  return obj;
}
```

You can now take advantage of the fact that `free(NULL)` is well-defined and make the parse function like this:

```
request_http_line* parse_http (request_http_line* request_line, const char* line)
{
  free(request_line->method);
  free(request_line->path);
  free(request_line->protocol);

  request_line->method = malloc (...);
  ...

  return request_line;
}
```

Meaning no matter if you pass a new or existing object to the parse function, it will always clean up old memory.

None of this code should be on the caller side, they shouldn't need to know the implementation details of your struct to use it.